# Machine-Generated Data Sources for Infobright Coding Competition

Tags: mysql

I'm looking at entering the Infobright Coding Competition.  They ask for public machine-generated data.  I don't want to create my own.  Anyone know where some exists?  Here's what I'm looking at: http://www.infobright.org/contest/2011q1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in the competition -- in the FAQ for the contest, we mention some good sources for publicly available datasets.  The forum post is here: http://www.infobright.org/forums/viewthread/2074/.

Cheers,

Jeff
Community Manager @ Infobright

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples they give is webserver logs: if you Google for "filetype:log" you'll find all sorts of accidentally public webserver logs.